# programmatically run a Test case

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can any one help me to write a program that executes a Test method?

i.e,

Generally to run a Test method in Visual Studio, user selects a 'Test Method' in 'Test Explorer window' and then clicks on "Run".

But i want my program to perform the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will differ greatly depends on the version of VS. If you work on VS 2010, you may peek how the https://github.com/quetzalcoatl/xvsr10/ is done for xUnit. If you work on VS2011/2012/2013 then peek in the xUnit's or nUnit's source code, I'm pretty sure they have TestRunners for those versions already.

Mind that those work from within the VS, using it's architecture. If you want to run it "outside" of the VisualStudio, then, well, all you need to do is to load the assembly, create the test class instance and run the method - all with Reflection. And you need to handle the Startup/Teardown etc points too. So, if you want to run it outside of VS, then probably it'd easier to again peek into the xUnit/nUnit/xxxx and use their runners. Oh, except the case when you use the Microsoft's Unit Testing framework provided with VS. Then you'll probably have to do it fomr scratch. But, you also might cut some bits with Reflector/etc from the microsoft.qualitytools.unittesting dlls. If I remembered the names correctly of course, but that's something close to it.

Comment: And you've also forgot to say what unittesting framework you are using. You know, that's quite important. xUnit? nUnit? MSTest? others?

Answer (score 4):

Test Explorer is just a wrapper around mstest.exe, that works in command line environment as well.

You can find information about arguments it accepts here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you mean i also have to create a wrapper that deals with MSTest.exe?

Comment: The simplest solution is, yes, write an MSTest wrapper. I am not fond of writing wrappers for .exe(s) but that's just the way it is. ...OR, you end up rolling your own so that the runner will be visible in VS and executable on its own.